# What does "-4,257m" mean in Google Earth?

Tags: oceanography, bathymetry

When I move my pointer around the pin (89.99 N) shown below, Google Earth displays the camera distance, latitude, longitude accordingly.

I'd just like to know what does "-4,257m" mean, pointed out by the red arrow.

Could someone give me a hint?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the ocean depth at that point, according to the Google Earth database.

Comment: For completeness sake : since `,` is used as decimal separator in some countries, the `,` above is used as a thousand separator. So the selected point is 4.2km deep, not just 4.2m.

Answer (score 3):

Google earth uses the EGM96 geoid as it's reference for altitude/depth. EGM96 is a model of the ocean surface that takes into account the fact that the earth isn't a sphere, and some account of regional variation in gravity. So the number is the difference between the sea floor and the ocean surface (geoid) at that point. WGS84, the system used by GPS, has a similar model, but less accuracy as it is older.

Only a small percentage of the oceans have been surveyed in detail so you shouldn't read too much into the precise number - it will be an estimate from, in mid ocean, what might be low resolution bathymetry.

Answer (score 0):

This is the elevation of the ocean floor, which is the negative of the depth.